# What is the minimum code necessary to provide review context?

Tags: discussion

I am currently attempting to reduce the number of unanswered questions on the Code Review Community. I’m doing this because I am concerned that we have dropped below 90% of questions answered and have remained there for a significant period, in fact we are closing in on dropping below 89%.

I am currently concentrating on questions with the C programming language tag. I am trying to answer as many questions as I can and close the questions that can’t be answered. Today I came across 2 very old questions:

1. [Windows AppLocker extension - Owner rule](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84122/windows-applocker-extension-owner-rule)
2. [Defining a char device driver protocol over uart at kernel level](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96190/defining-a-char-device-driver-protocol-over-uart-at-kernel-level)

and voted to close them because they were Missing Review Context. A moderator agreed to close one of the questions immediately but had concerns about the second question.

Based on that discussion in the 2nd Monitor I feel that we need to revisit what is the minimum code necessary to be able to do a code review. I think that the minimum necessary code depends on the language the code is written in. We already have rules for the minimum SQL code necessary to do a code review, I am suggesting that we come up with a set of guide lines for a minimum of necessary code for each language with a language tag.

I propose that the minimum necessary code description be listed in a Meta question, but also added to each programming language tag. We need to be able to point to the minimum code necessary when we close a question as Missing Review Context.